# Rsync over ssh copies all files every time

Tags: ssh, rsync

We are using `rsync` to backup one external drive to another external drive. When the two drives are connected to our Ubuntu machine, it works perfectly:

```
rsync -avzh --exclude='_quarantine'  /media/archive00/ /media/archiveX/archive00/
```

However, when we try to do the same operation on the same drive connected to a local server over ssh, it tries to copy all the files every time, not updating only those that have different update times:

```
rsync -avzh -e ssh --exclude='_quarantine' /media/archive00/ my_user@10.0.0.12:/media/archiveX/archive00/
```

The first 10 lines when I include the `-i` option:

```
sending incremental file list
.d..t...... BTEVC/
<f..t...... BTEVC/Untitled41.mov
<f..t...... BTEVC/UntitledX100.mov
<f..t...... BTEVC/gfxCardStatus-2.3.zip
<f..t...... BTEVC/BTEVCformBook/aud.ECPP.SCAmp/0d20180825203546p+13057989928.m4a
<f..t...... BTEVC/BTEVCformBook/aud.ECPP.SCAmp/0d20180826210032p+13057989928.m4a
<f..t...... BTEVC/BTEVCformBook/aud.ECPP.SCAmp/0d20180827174045p+18002662278.m4a
<f..t...... BTEVC/BTEVCformBook/aud.ECPP.SCAmp/0d20180904171935p+12123769623.m4a
<f..t...... BTEVC/BTEVCformBook/aud.ECPP.SCAmp/0d20180905190057p+18593229553.m4a
```

Comment: Is the target filesystem some sort of Windows filesystem that stores timestamps with imprecise precision, or does the target filesystem not preserve permission and/or user/group ownerships?  Also, the default remote transport for `rsync` _is_ `ssh`, so using `-e ssh` is not necessary.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a owner/group issues. Try with options `--usermap=*:<owner-id-according-to-target-FS>` and `--groupmap=*:<goup-owner-id-according-to-target-FS>`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the other machine is debian, but the two drives are formatted to exFAT. @SYN hmm, it seems with the `--usermap` and `--groupmap` options it is still copying the files every time (but interestingly not the unlisted files, i.e. those with a '.' before them). Realized also that /etc/fstab was specifying that the drive on the server be mounted as root, and changed that also, but same results.

Comment: Add the `-i` flag and add the output to your question.  It will show what criteria rsync thinks is responsible for the copy.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Ok, I added the first 10 lines of output.

Answer (score 4):

One underlying problem is that "*the two drives are formatted to exFAT*" (from a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552349/rsync-over-ssh-copies-all-files-every-time#comment1025359_552349)).

The [exFAT filesystem](http://www.ntfs.com/exfat-time-stamp.htm) can only maintain timestamps to a two-second resolution, so you need to tell `rsync` this.

Fortuitously it has an option to manage this inaccuracy:

> `--modify-window` When comparing two timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps as being equal if they differ by no more than the modify-window value. This is normally 0 (for an exact match), but you may find it useful to set this to a larger value in some situations. In particular, when transferring to or from an MS Windows FAT filesystem (which represents times with a 2-second resolution), --`modify-window=1` is useful (allowing times to differ by up to 1 second).

Try `rsync --modify-window=1 ...`.

Comment: `--modify-window=1` doesn't seem to do it, but it is good to know for the future that exFAT has this behavior.

Comment: I needed `--modify-window=2` to really get it to work. It's unfortunate that it needs that much slop, but for my purposes I can work within that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

From your output:

```
<f..t...... BTEVC/Untitled41.mov
```

The lowercase `t` indicates that rsync is (attempting to) set the time on the destination to match the source.  Everything else after the `f` is blank indicating they match (so you don't have to look at user permissions being the cause).

You might want to investigate the times before and after a run to see how they differ.

Suggestions:

- Try `--inplace`.  See if anything changes
- Copy a single file (so the output is smaller) and then up the verbosity.  With `-vvv` you can see it try to set the transfer time similar to:

  ```
  [...]
  recv mapped dest.file of size 598
  got file_sum
  set modtime of .dest.file.5s3OoJ to (1573876681) Fri Nov 15 19:58:01 2019
  renaming .dest.file.5s3OoJ to dest.file
  [...]
  ```

See if anything odd is reported around that point (and that the actual timestamp matches afterward)

```
$ stat dest.file
  File: dest.file
  Size: 598             Blocks: 1          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 8788005h/142114821d     Inode: 19140298416802240  Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (197609/ compusr)   Gid: (197121/    None)
Access: 2019-11-15 20:26:49.597544100 -0800
Modify: 2019-11-15 19:58:01.309978600 -0800
Change: 2019-11-15 20:26:49.598968100 -0800
 Birth: 2019-11-15 20:26:49.594376800 -0800
```

Comment: Interesting, `--inplace` does not solve the problem, but your answer helped uncover a half-solution. Started reading about `--inplace` in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/674634/833394), and realized that `--no-whole-file` is assumed across a network. If `--whole-file` is used, it still copies the files that were there from before again, but at least it starts where it left off.

Comment: @BTEVC a big part of using `rsync` across a network is that it will only copy changed parts of changed files. Try to avoid forcing `--whole-file` because that removes the advantage.

Comment: Interestingly also, the behavior is the same as with `--whole-file` if only one file is transferred without that option. Will try to look at the details of the transfer to see if there's anything helpful in the output with the `-vvv` option tomorrow.

Comment: @roaima ok, right, good to know

Answer (score -1):

What about using the "-u"-option? This will update only newer files.

The "-a"-option only sets the options below:

```
-a, --archive archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
...
-r, recursive
-l, links
-p, perms
-t, times
-g, groups
-o, owner
-D, device specials
```

With the "-u"-option i never had any problems only copying new files. So it should be:

```
rsync -avzhu -e ssh --exclude='_quarantine' /media/archive00/ my_user@10.0.0.12:/media/archiveX/archive00
```

Comment: No `-u` doesn't do it either, unfortunately.